# Listview threshold limit reached despite returning less than 5000

Tags: list-view, list-view-threshold, row-limit

I have a sharepoint list with 20k+ records. I'm using the ID filter to get the records where ID is less than 1,500. I know ID field is automatically indexed so I should have only 1,500 records returned in my view, but if I add another filter after the first one then I receive the error that list view threshold has been reached. Why is that If with the first filter I'm sure i'm only getting the first 1,500 records?

Project:Region is a lookup column:

[image]

Comment: Here your ID filter for less than 1500 items works because your query does not have to scan all the records in this case because ID column is by default indexed. But when you add another filter i.e. `Project:Region` then may be your query forces to scan all the records to get the filtered data.  So it is not only about the how much record you fetch but how much records your query scans to get the filtered data/result.

Comment: Refer this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx

Comment: I would expect that 2nd filter condition is applied on the result set from 1st filter condition. If I'm below the threshold limit then it should work fine. Why would it had to query the full list on 2nd filter? Shouldn't the filters work based on the result set from previous?